# Flutter. How to catch errors of 'rendering library' in --release mode?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, error-handling, release

```
 FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    for (final listener in _errorsListeners) {
      listener.call(details);
    }
  };
```

so, when details appear,
some of the inner listeners, check there is details.library is 'rendering library'.

In debug mode there is errors of 'rendering library'.
In release mode there is none.

How do i get them in release mode?

advice, or maybe uhhhh, solution may be

Comment: refer following this might help in your case
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/130967